# How to use notification with sound and vibration?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

How do you allow the device to vibrate or make a sound when a notification is launched.

Ive heard of the FLAGS. But how would i use them for Sound and Vibration?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Edit** In Android v4 support library, there is [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) and the method `setSound` which will work if using that class instead. However, the info below will still work.

```
Notification notif ... //create your notification

notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

That adds sound and vibrate.

Always remember to check the docs. They have a LOT of answers, such as this one:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

That has the info I posted above as well as info on how to use a custom sound or vibrate and also the entire process of creating a notification.

**EDIT:** Don't forget to include the [Vibrate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#VIBRATE) permission in your manifest.

Comment: How to disable this notification sound? I need to mute the default sound. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe you can just not include the line `notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;`

Answer (score 20):

```
Notification notification // new notification object.
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

Shows all the default notifications. (sound, vibration, led)